# How to load jQuery in TOP of wp_footer?

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have added this code to load Google hosted jQuery

```
function replace_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'replace_jquery', 0 );
```

A plugin requires jQuery and it is placed in `wp_footer` with priority value of `19`. So I want to add jQuery before that. As you can see, I have given the above code a priority of `0`. But when in the output HTML, the jQuery link is added in the last. My guess is that because `wp_enqueue_script` has default priority of `20`. If I am right, How do I over ride to load it first ?

Answer (score 1):

To properly enqueue jQuery, it's usually done with `wp_enqueue_scripts`, there's no need to load it from cdn as jQuery library are provides in the wp-includes folder of WordPress.

Only wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); is required.

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_jquery');
```

If you really want to replace jQuery with the cdn link, it's better to register and enqueue it with this function.

Comment: The problem is it is loaded in the head of the document. It becomes render blocking and slows down the page. two of my plugins need jQuery but both are added in the footer. So it is enough if I add jQuery in the footer. So what i'm asking is, Is there a way to control the loading 'wp_enqueue_script' so that I could load it with first priority in the 'footer'

Comment: Did you try to make it work like this ? I'm only talking about jQuery library not your plugin script that can be add to the footer. I never saw jQuery enqueue in the footer. The blocking and slows comes from the cdn load, if the jQuery version doesn't fit to you, copy and load it from your theme or plugin.

Comment: Yes, I also tried adding the local version. The above method you said loads in the head of the page. Page speed tool says that it is render blocking. It doesn't matter which version of jQuery is added, I just want to add it in a non-render blocking way.

Comment: Remove https: leave only //Ajax...., The function will detect the right protocol

Comment: Does that have to do anything with my question !?

Comment: About your last comments....

Comment: Sorry, I said local version and the CDN version of jQuery, not the https or http version. I also tried adding a through <script> tags in the HTML, but since they are not registered, it looks like my plugin won't recognize it.

Comment: You maybe need to enqueue all your script in the same wp_enqueue_scripts, and manage the dependency parameter. First one need to be jQuery and after the plugin script with a jQuery dependency parameter (register), and at the very last end , enqueue the plugin handle. In the question you only put jQuery not the other scripts.